# How can I code the HTML to force a browser to display a PDF from a linked web page?

Tags: html, css, pdf, web

I need to link a PDF from another website to my page. When I got the link in an email, it opens on a website (in Firefox, also works in Safari). Chrome wants to download the PDF. Can I apply any code in HTML or CSS to make it work properly, i.e. open a new page or tab and display the PDF there? Or open on my page, that's fine, too.

Answer (score 1):

For PDF preview in a browser the following request headers should be specified:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"
```

For PDF or image download in a browser the following request headers should be specified:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"
```